# Unable to delete a page, even with macros

Tags: microsoft-word, vba, macros

I have a 2 page file (output from a web, I do not control it).
Somehow I cannot delete the second page at all.

Tried all sort of macros from the web, nothing works.

This is the file.
https://filebin.net/18td6mriqmi6nrm4

Is there some sort of hard forced delete code?
I tried

- Deleting manually
- Deleting using all macros/scripts I found online
  Example of macro

```
Sub test()

  Dim objRange As Range
  Dim strPage As String
  Dim objDoc As Document
  Dim nSplitItem As Long

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 
  ' Initialize and enter page numbers of pages to be deleted.
  Set objDoc = ActiveDocument
  strPage = 2

  ' Find specified pages and highlight their contents.
  For nSplitItem = nSplitItem To 0 Step -1
    With ActiveDocument
      Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToPage, Which:=wdGoToAbsolute, Count:=Split(strPage, ",")(nSplitItem)
      Set objRange = .Bookmarks("\Page").Range
      objRange.Delete
    End With
  Next nSplitItem
 
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

This macro works for page 1 but not page 2.

If not, can someone help me with a macro to "Save as" the exact file with page 1 without page 2?

Thank you

Comment: "*Everything I tried didn't work*", but what did you try? Can you please edit your question to include that (preferably in a bullet point list)?

Comment: See above. Manually doesn't work, any script I tried from the web doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried deleting it manually through the [**Go To** dialog](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/delete-a-page-in-word-174fedd3-b4e5-42e4-a4d0-5e25127a1404)?:

> 1. Click or tap anywhere in the page you want to delete, press Ctrl+G.
> 2. In the Enter page number box, type \page.
> 3. Press Enter on your keyboard, and then select Close.
> 4. Verify that a page of content is selected, and then press Delete on your keyboard.

Alternatively [there are instructions on the Word support site](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/delete-a-blank-page-a5efa26e-6a21-4ac8-81ce-220a46d105a8) on how to delete blank pages at the end of a document:

> 1. Press Ctrl+Shift+8 (⌘+8 on a Mac) to show paragraph marks.
> 2. Select the paragraph mark.
> 3. Select inside the Font size box, type 01, and then press Enter.
>    The paragraph now fits on the preceding page, removing the unwanted blank page.
> 4. Press Ctrl+Shift+8 again to hide the paragraph marks (⌘+8 on a Mac).

Checking the document I see that the first page ends with a **[section break (next page)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/insert-a-section-break-eef20fd8-e38c-4ba6-a027-e503bdf8375c)**. Naturally, after that section break Word creates a next page. Unless you delete that section break or change it to **section break (continuous)** you'll have a blank second page after the first.

Comment: The only way I can manipulate the file is either manually or via macro. So far failed both to remove that page. how can I remove the page break?

Comment: That's a different question and as with the current question it needs some research of your own. [Here are the search results on superuser](https://superuser.com/search?q=remove+page+break) and here are the [duckduckgo results](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=how+to+delete+page+break+in+word). If what you find does not answer your question, feel free to edit the current question and include why the existing answers were not helpful.

Comment: Manually, go into Draft view and show formatting marks. Work with a copy because section breaks carry a lot of layout formatting. It is a Section break, not a page break. There is a huge difference.